# Unexpected connection attempt from Microsoft Outlook Communications

Tags: networking, microsoft-outlook, windows-10-v1709

I recently installed ESET Smart Security and put the firewall in interactive mode.  I just got a notification that "Microsoft Outlook Communications" is attempting to connect on TCP 443 to "client-office365-tas.msedge.net".

I have no Office apps installed.  I don't even have a mail account set up in Windows.

Why is this connection being made?